# Combobox Dropdown Displays in Wrong Place

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

[image: combox]

Got a ajaxcontroltoolkit combox. Somehow the dropdown isnt showing to the left(see image).

.Net code

```
<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="cbState" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DropDownStyle="Dropdownlist" AutoCompleteMode="None" ItemInsertLocation="Append" CssClass="searchcontentCombobox" />
```

CSS

```
.searchcontentCombobox .ajax__combobox_inputcontainer {}
.searchcontentCombobox .ajax__combobox_textboxcontainer input {border:0;width:160px;height:22px;padding:3px 10px 3px 7px;background:#1f1f1f;color:#fff;}
.searchcontentCombobox .ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer button {border:0;background:url(../img/menu_searchcontent.gif) no-repeat center right;}
.searchcontentCombobox .ajax__combobox_itemlist {}
```

Any idea?

Comment: So you're trying to control where the drop down field renders? I dont think that is possible since the browser is responsible for doing that. The best you could do would be to make your own elements and show / hide / style the appropriately.

Comment: i am trying to align the dropdown on the left in line with select.

Answer (score 8):

This css worked for me to get the dropdown list to align.

```
.ajax__combobox_itemlist
{
    position:fixed !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I put the combobox in a div.  The div has no positioning set up.

Then I put this in my stylesheet:

```
.ajax__combobox_itemlist
{
    position:relative !important; 
    height: 100px !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
}
```

The dropdown list that pops up is then bound to the top left corner of the div.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar happen to me.  I had to add a meta tag to ensure ie8 was in the doctype declaration.  You can see if you're having the same issue by using the developer toolbar or firebug.  Once I changed the doctype to emulate ie8 all was good.

Comment: unfortunately this is happening on all browsers.